# How to remove these (screenshot) unpinned items (red box in image) from window 10 navigation?

Tags: windows-10-quick-access

So I have this side window navigation panel where I don't want to see these "quick access" items as if I want to see them I can just click on quick success. So how can I remove these unpinned items but still keep quick access items in quick access on the top listed folder? I want them to never show up on this navigation bar ever again. I hope there is some registry edit way to fix this.

[image]

Comment: Right click, then remove them.

Comment: Just right click and select `Remove from Quick access`.  There is no mechanic to prevent them from being added to the quick access list.  You can also just clear the current list and add only the items you want.

Comment: Yes seems that's only option. Doesn't seem like another way to remove except right click and remove. I could succeed to remove other clutters by registry and playing around with settings but this is no way going away.

Comment: They are stored in the registry somewhere, don't know where though.